# Play Again button works wrongly

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit

I made a play again button in my game and I used **SKTransition** for restarting game. When I touch Play Again button, new scene comes. But this scene's objects are bigger than the last scene's. And Scene is frozen. I can't play a game when I touch play again button. What should I do? Here is my all of code about button and restart scene :

```
let playAgain: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, 450, 1000))

class GameScene: SKScene {
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let pransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0) //create a transition
    let gamePlayScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") // create a new scene from your file (let variableName = NameOfGameFile(fileNamed: "NameOfGameFile")
    self.view?.presentScene(gamePlayScene!, transition: pransition) // present the scene with the transition
}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches{...



    if(..){...}
    else{
            playAgain.setTitle("Play Again", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            playAgain.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 50)

            playAgain.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            playAgain.tag = 1
            self.view!.addSubview(playAgain)
```

Comment: I do not think you are showing the problem.  I have a feeling it has to do with how you handle your scene scalingmode.  In here, you are setting it to the Default, which is .Fill.  What are you using in the first scene you present

Comment: It's my first scene. Moreover I have just one scene.I want to constantly replay the same scene when I touch play again button .  I'm new in swift. All of the code is about the play again button and I have no more code about changing scene or play again button.

Comment: You are adding a new scene every time.... But you have to present the first scene somewhere else, because buttonpress cant work with out a scene present

Comment: It is reasons like this that presenting a new scene inside of an old scene is a bad approach,  i wish apple didnt take this approach,  another problem you may be having is you are retaining the old scene with the new scene when you do the transition,  and the old scene is not deleting properly

Comment: I can definately tell you your old scene is not deleting because your press button code is inside the scene, but your playagain button is global (Very bad habit, I recommend stopping this at once),  by attaching the buttonpressed to the button this way, it will never die, and you will run out of memory quick

Comment: So, Should I add new scene for every play again touches? I understand you but If I do your says, I should add scene infinite times. I think I can do this with just one scene. When the players touch play again button, one scene can start every time.

Comment: you ARE adding a new scene everytime, I am not suggesting that.  If you want to just use the same scene over and over, you need to create a reset function (which is silly).  What you should be doing, is subclassing SKView, and have SKView manage the scenes and the buttons, then inside the view, you can make a new scene, and manage your code better.

Comment: Thanks for all of your explain. Sometimes I can't understand some sentences because of my English. So, I'm researching how can I make reset button in **gamescene.swift**.  But I can't find solution. If you explain how can I make reset button I will be very happy. Because It is what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104670/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-uzaylibeyb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is when you create a transition to the game scene through the play button, you are not setting the scene size. i just plugged your code and it does what you say. in swift, it is a good practice to set the size and aspect ratio of the scene when you creating a transition, lets say back to the game or from game to a end scene such as win scene or loose scene etc. the easy way would be to add the scene aspect ratio after declaring the game scene constant like the following code block:

```
let pransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0)
    let gamePlayScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
    gamePlayScene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    self.view?.presentScene(gamePlayScene!, transition: transition)
    self.playAgain.removeFromSuperview()
```

i generally like to create a wait for a second or two for the dramatic aspects of the game so i use the following which is very similar to what you do but creates bit of delay before the scene get fired, the following is what i use, feel free to change it if you want.

```
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
    let theGameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    theGameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    let theTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0)
    let changeScene = SKAction.runBlock{
        self.scene?.view?.presentScene(theGameScene, transition: theTransition)
    }

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, changeScene])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(sequence, count: 1))
```

good luck and continue coding and ask questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend.I have **override func touchesBegan()** in SKScene class. Still I have problem. When I touch play again button game is started. But **override func touchesBegan()** is not working.

Comment: I added **self.playAgain.removeFromSuperview()**. Then everything is okay.

Comment: Ha sorry about that play again. I actually copy and pasted the code I was using. Glad that I could help.